# appropriate MVC structure for a forum

Tags: php, model-view-controller

I want to use a good mvc naming convention for a forum im creating.

I wonder, should I use this structure:

```
controller: threads
model: threads_model (eg. $threads_model->get_all_threads, $threads_model->add_thread, $threads_model->add_post, $threads_model->add_comment)

controller: tags
model: tags_model (eg. $tags_model->get_all_tags, $tags_model->add_tag)

controller: users
model: users_model (eg. $users_model->get_all_users, $users_model->add_user)
```

or

```
controller: content
model: content_model (eg. $content_model->get_all_tags, $content_model->get_all threads...)

controller: users
model: users_model (eg. $users_model->get_all_users, $users_model->add_user)
```

this is my first time using mvc so I want to know what is best practice for this. should i like in the first example separate every "thing" (tags, threads, users...) or should I use the second one? further more, should i in the first example separate comments and posts as well so they will be their own controllers/models?

would be good if someone gave me some good mvc pattern for forums.

Comment: thats to ugly, usualy programmers work one month to plan a mvc for a forum and you want that we post something that even is wrong and is unusable. for me this question  cant be answered.

Comment: it was never intented for u to put down hours of work to give me full description. i just wanted to discuss it generally so i wasnt way off the right thinking.. im a beginner of mvc as well as programmering

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Over the 2 you have posted, id say the 1st structure is best. Think about your system as separate entities, and the relations between them. As a simple example

```
Thread
Reply
User
Tag
```

In this case som appropriate associations would be..

```
User can create many threads
User can create many replies

Reply Belongs to a User
Reply Belongs to a thread

Thread belongs to a user
Thread has many replies
Thread has many tags

Tag has many threads
```

Once the associations are made its a bit clearer to think of the methods needed, such as:

```
**User**
Get Threads: Returns all threads created by this user
Get Replies: Returns all replies created by this user

**Thread**
Get User: Returns the User that created this thread
Get Replies: Return all replies to this thread

**Reply**
Get User: Returns the User that created this reply
Get Thread: Returns the Thread that this user belongs to
```

There would obviously be more methods for example in the user model you may want to return a particular thread by an id so you would also have a GetThread method that you would pass an id.

Hope this gets you thinking a bit!

One further point is that in your models, such as your Tag model, you have a method addTag, as far as i am aware, you wouldn't really want this method in your model, as then it could only be called by a tag. If you had to create a tag to add a tag you'd get pretty stuck. Id move this into the controller.

Comment: thx for a great description. just one question. if i want eg create a thread. is it best to do it by $threads_model->create_thread($user_id) or $users_model->create_thread?

Comment: No problem.
Creation,Updating and Deletion of models is usually handed by the controller. You can either put the create() method inside the controller, or, if you are using classes, make it a Thread class method. Then in the controller, just call Thread.create() and pass the parameters you need such as title, body, user_id. The way i think of MVC is that Models define the data objects, Controllers perform actions with/on those objects, and Views display the objects. Hope it helps.

Comment: ok i c. so the controller is going to handle it. but lets say i've got 2 controllers (cause it was the best solution) one users and one threads, should i then create a new thread with users/create_thread or threads/create_thread?

Comment: Out of curiousity, what programming language are you using?
To be honest you can use either of those methods, id recommend keeping it within the Thread controller as its a thread you are dealing with so have Thread_controller->create_thread. That way, if later you have another entity that can create a thread, you dont have to make another method.

Comment: ok then i know. it is just to use common sense then. im using php:) a very easy to learn language..but the hardest part is to learn how to code the right structure:)

Answer (score 2):

Your first structure would be better, separate it all from the start, you never know when a future feature will need some tags index json or something.

Each (most) controller has it's CRUD actions  index, view, edit, new, save etc

The php auto load function can take a model name and then look into the models directory for a file to require().

Yes separate comments and posts, into different models and controllers, the post controller will have a view/show action to render the post that might have a form with an action="" pointing to the save/create action of the comments controller.

The "normal" MVC filesystem structure might be:

```
/app/
     controllers/
                 content/                <- controller name
                       home.php          <- actions that require(../../views/content/home.php)
                       view.php
                 users/
                       index.php
                       view.php
                 tags/
                       edit.php
     models/
                 content.php             <-   class Content{ }
                 user.php
                 tag.php
     helpers/
                 application.php       <- grouped up functions for areas of the system
                 tag_helper.php
                 content_helper.php
     views/                             <- templates
                 users/
                        index.php
                        user.php
                        views.php
     public/
                 css/
                        layout.css
                        typography.css
                        style.css
                 images/
                        logo.png
                 js/
                        global.js
                        content.js
                 assets/
                        users/
                                000234.png     <- e.g. profile images
```

This structure is largely taken from the Rails structure which is very organized.

Comment: @streetparade, of course they don't what are you talking about?

Comment: your controller has content and has a home view

Comment: Who said they output? they are scripts!  views output